# CSS transition on data-percentage attribute change

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I have found a code that makes a Circular progress bar, and changed it a bit to grow on click from 1 to other number. Later on I wanted to add transition but it doesn't seem to work, the progress bar changes without transition

```
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Aapn8/8362/

Someone have an idea how to make transition work?

Comment: it's not css property, transition won't work for it

Comment: is there a way around to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @user1850903 wrote - transition doesn't work in that way.

You can use `setInterval()` to get the effect you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/3j0vxx77/17/

Comment: I'm glad I could help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

your drawCircle funciton uses canvas and is not influenced by CSS.
CSS only applies to html tags, not to lines drown on canvas.

Quote from WIKI: "*Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) is a style sheet language used for describing the presentation of a document **written in a markup language***"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets